# ООП. Объект класса типа класса-родителя

Tags: java, ооп, классы, объекты, типы

В примерах на тему ООП часто замечаю, что объект, созданный на основе определённого класса сохраняют в переменную типа "класс-родитель". Поясню на примере:

```
class Pet {
    // реализация
}


class Cat extends Pet {
    // реализация
}
```

Затем, в главном методе:

```
Pet myCat = new Cat();
```

"По классике" переменная myCat должна была бы объявиться типа Cat, что логично. Я заметил, что таким образом можно группировать в коллекции объекты разных типов, но имеющих одного предка, однако вся функциональность таких объектов будет ограничена этим самым предком.

Хочу узнать, для чего так делается, и что с этого можно поиметь или потерять.

Comment: В корне неверная догадка что функционал будет ограничен родительскими методами, вы всегда можете явно указать тип и обратится к методам фактически созданного дочернего класса... пример на делфи(обращения к дочернему методу, когда класс обьявлен как родительский) `Cat(myCat).someMethodOfClassCat();` альтернатива - `(myCat as Cat).someMethodOfClassCat();`

Comment: Хорошо. Но для чего вообще так делать?

Comment: Потому что так лучше с точки зрения логики, класс расширяет функционал родителя.

Comment: Т.е. никаких других причин на это нет, и можно объявлять переменную данного конкретного типа, если это не помешает логическому восприятию?

Comment: Несовсем так, яркий пример для чего - посмотрите как устроен VCL(Delphi), там это очень ярко показано... Как у вас в примере - если вы хотите покормить - вам не важно кот или собака, но как только вы захотите чтобы оно помяукало - вам придется обратится к конкретному дочернему классу

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно взять пример на основе Java. Вы объявляете объект коллекции в каком-либо методе, но при этом определяете его интерфейсом List

```
List<> myList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Ваш объект будет использовать методы, которые есть у интерфейса List, при этом можно скастовать объект к реализации ArrayList и использовать методы ArrayList

```
(ArrayList)myList.get(0);
```

но, если так не делать, а использовать строго методы, описанные в интерфейсе List, вы в любой момент можете изменить реализацию ArrayList, например, на LinkedList, для этого придется исправить только одну строчку в коде, в определении вашей переменной, а весь остальной код менять не придется.

```
List<> myList = new LinkedList<>();
```

Так, например, ArrayList позволяет очень быстро обращаться к элементам - сложность O(1), а LinkedList для обращения к элементу имеет сложность O(n). В то же время, ArrayList гораздо более долго вставляет элементы в середину коллекции, а для LinkedList это очень быстрая операция. Когда вы начинаете писать код, вы описываете вашу переменную каким-то общим классом, а в последующем имеете возможность быстро перейти к более выгодной реализации данного класса.

Answer (score 1):

Приведенный вами пример

```
Pet myCat = new Cat();
```

в таком виде имеет смысл только в "ссылочных" языках программирования, в которых `myCat` на самом деле не является переменной типа `Pet` (как вы ошибочно предположили), а является *ссылкой*, которая может ссылаться на объект любого типа в подыерархии классов с корнем `Pet`. Такая ссылка будет вести себя *полиморфно*, т.е. несмотря на то, что внешне она имеет тип `Pet`, она будет вести себя как `Cat` (в рамках общего интерфейса).

Собственно именно такой полиморфизм и призван продемонстрировать приведенный вами пример.

В языке С++, где "ссылочность" типа нужно объявлять явно, ваш исходный пример не имел бы смысла. В С++ вам бы пришлось делать то же самое, например, через указатель

```
Pet *myCat = new Cat();
```

Здесь вы явно видите, что на самом деле никакой переменной типа `Pet` в левой части нет. Есть лишь *указатель* (или другая форма ссылки) на `Pet`, который фактически указывает на `Cat`.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос иллюстрирует типичную реализацию принципа "Полиморфизм" в ООП.

Для понимания этого принципа необходимо понять несколько важных моментов:

1. В классическом ООП объект создается на основании какого-то типа (класса) и в течении жизни этого объекта тип, на основании которого он создан НЕ МОЖЕТ БЫТЬ ИЗМЕНЕН.
   Исключения составляют некоторые языки программирования, в которых уже созданный объект может модифицироваться - к этому объекту могут добавляться новые методы и прочие ехтеншны, но это не важно в контексте обсуждаемого вопроса. Одним из следствий того, что тип объекта в течении его жизни не изменятся является то, что вся реализация методов и свойств класса, на основании которого создан данный объект будет использоваться в полном объеме. НЕЗАВИСИМО от того, каким образом вызывается тот или иной метод данного объекта. Таким образом, если мы вызываем методы данного объекта, мы всегда получаем поведение типа, на основании которого создан данный объект. Из вопроса ТС - методы переменной `myCat` будут выполнять поведение класса `Cat` хотя тип переменной будет `Pet`.
2. Тип переменной определяет набор тех методов, которые можно будет использовать для данной переменной. Исключение составляют некоторые объектные типы, которые позволяют вызывать методы объектов по их названию, например тип `object` во многих языках программирования может использоваться для вызова любых методов объекта без его типизации. При таком вызове будет произведено позднее связывание и если у такого объекта вызываемый метод существует, то он будет выполнен, если не существует, то будет выдана ошибка времени выполнения !не ошибка времени компиляции!.
3. В переменную типа базового класса можно совершенно безопасно поместить ссылку на объект любого потомка этого базового класса. Что и делается совершенно справедливо в строке кода из вопроса ТС
    
   `Pet myCat = new Cat();`

   от этого объект НЕ изменит своего типа, но сам тип переменной базового класса ограничит набор методов, которые можно вызвать благодаря этой переменной. Например, если в классе `Cat` определен публичный метод `CatMyau`, то вызвать этот метод из переменной `myCat` не получится, так как этого метода нет в классе `Pet`.
4. Сделав коллекцию объектов базового класса мы можем обрабатывать ЛЮБЫЕ объекты-потомки данного класса. Например, мы можем сделать коллекцию, которая будет содержать домашних питомцев, для класса `Pet` мы можем определить абстрактный публичный метод `Voice`, а для всех потомков базового класса сделать реализацию этого метода. Например, `Cat` будет мяукать, а собака - лаять. При обходе в цикле по домашним животным мы можем вызывать для типа переменной `Pet` метод `Voice`, и, в зависимости от того, объект какого класса был помещен в нашу коллекцию мы услышим голос того или иного животного. Кошки будут мяукать, собаки гавкать.