# Базовый вопрос ООП по теме наследования

Tags: java, ооп, наследование, extend

Я только в начале своего пути в программировании. Есть вопрос, на который не могу найти ответ (может, плохо искал). Пишу все это на Java, но подозреваю, что это общий вопрос по ООП. Перейдем к сути

**Есть класс `Employee`**

```
public class Employee {

private String name;

public Employee(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
```

}

**Есть класс `Manager`, который наследуется от `Employee`**

```
public class Manager extends Employee{

private int count;

public Manager(String name, int count) {
    super(name);
    this.count = count;
}

public int getCount(){
    return count;
}
```

Когда я создаю новый экземпряр

```
Employee e = new Manager("ada",5);
```

и пытаюсь вызвать метод из класса `Manager` `e.getCount()`, компилятор говорит

> "Cannot resolve method `getCount()` in `Employee`"

Если прошу отобразить тип объекта e:

```
System.out.println((Object)e.getClass().getName());
```

то на консоль выводится сообщение: `"Manager"`

Но раз это объект с типом Manager, то почему тогда нельзя вызвать метод `getCount()`?

Comment: [Зачем нужен upcast (повышающее приведение типа)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/433315/179763), [Причины использования DownCast](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/432197/179763)

Comment: [Ответ на подобный вопрос здесь на форуме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/934104/ООП-Объект-класса-типа-класса-родителя/936065#936065)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно различать две вещи: тип переменной и тип объекта.

`Employee e` определяет переменную типа `Employee`. Тип перменной влияет на:

1. какие операции с этой переменной можно делать
2. в частности, ссылки на какие объекты переменная может хранить (т.е. что можно ей присвоить)

Присваивать переменной можно только ссылки на объекты того же класса (т.е. `Employee`) или его наследников. Доступные операции - это (грубо) все публичные методы и поля, которые есть в `Employee`. Все это проверяется компилятором на момент компиляции кода с этой переменной.

Теперь про тип объекта (или по другому экземпляра). Объекты создаются с помощью `new ИмяТипа(...)`. Тип объекта определяет какие в принципе операции объект поддерживает (какие методы и поля у него есть). Но важно, что в зависимости от того, как к объекту обращаемся, не все операции могут быть доступны.

В вашем примере создается объект типа `Manager` и присваивается переменной типа `Employee`. Так как объект типа `Manager`, то при запросе его типа `e.getClass()` вы получаете `Manager`. Но так как доступ идет через переменную типа `Employee`, то доступны только операции определенные в `Employee` и вызвать `getCount` нельзя.

Можно сделать явное приведение типа `(Manager)e` и у такого выражения уже будет тип `Manager` т.е. его можно присвоить переменной типа `Manager` или вызвать метод определенный в `Manager`:

```
((Manager)e).getCount(); // это допустимо
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому что у вас переменная (то есть `Employee e`) типа Employee. Проще говоря переменная `е` не знает о методе `getCount()`, он знает только о методе `getName()`

Представьте вот такую сценарию. Например вы где то посреди программы сделали вот так `e = new Employee("Jack");`. Теперь переменная `е` ссылается на объект типа Employee и у этого объекта точно нет метода `getCount()`

Comment: спасибо! А почему тогда System.out.println((Object)e.getClass().getName()); возвращает Manager?

Comment: Добавил поправку, Прочитайте ещё раз

Answer (score -1):

В приведенном примере `e` - это *ссылка* на экземпляр `Employee`, являющийся подобъектом экземпляра `Manager`. Соответственно непосредственно через ссылку можно обращаться к полям и методам, объявленным именно в в `Employee`, хотя и был создан новый объект `Manager`.

Comment: а можете, пожалуйста, пояснить значение слова подобъект? Что значит "подобъект экземпляра Manager"

Comment: @VadimDorofeev Раз `Manager` наследует от `Employee`, то созданные экземпляры `Manager` будет содержать в себе по экземпляру `Employee`. Получается по типу матрешки.

Comment: @user7860670 вы используете неправильную терминологию. В этом примере нет _экземпляра_ `Employee`. И нет ссылки на экземпляр `Employee`. Есть экземпляр `Manager` и переменная типа `Employee`, которая хранит ссылку на экземпляр (объект) класса `Manager`.

Answer (score -1):

Вы столкнулись с одним из аспектов наследования – сокрытие.

Когда используется базовый класс (/ абстрактный класс / интерфейс), в Вашем случае:

```java
Employee e = new Manager("ada",5);
```

для вызова будет доступен только метод getName() (т.е. только доступные поля и методы базового класса).

Можете привести тип и тогда будет доступен getCount():

```java
((Manager)e).getCount() // Но тогда подумайте, что-то не так с иерархией.
```

Если посмотреть по иерархии наследования:

```
Object    // Object o = new Manager();   - доступны только поля и методы Object 
  |
Employee  // Employee e = new Manager(); - доступны только поля и методы Employee и Object
  |
Manager   // Manager m = new Manager();  - доступны все поля и методы Manager, Employee и Object.
```

Можно порассуждать о принципах ООП и SOLID, но подумайте что именно нужно и как это будет использоваться. Если должны быть getName() и getCount(), то они должны быть в базовом классе.
А может будет отдельная группа менеджерский должностей и только у них будет getCount(). Тогда можно добавить интерфейс:

```
interface IManager {
    int getCount();
}
...
class Manager extends Employee implements IManager {
...
class TopManager extends Employee implements IManager {
...
IManager m = new Manager();
m.getCount();
IManager t = new TopManager();
t.getCount();
```